# Is there a guide to path referencing in PHP?

Tags: php, directory-structure

I know how to include files that are in folders further down the heirachy but I have trouble finding my way back up.
I decided to go with the set_include_path to default all further includes relative to a path 2 levels up but don't have the slightest clue how to write it out.

Is there a guide somewhere that details path referencing for PHP?

Answer (score 2):

I tend to use **[dirname](https://www.php.net/dirname)** to get the current path and then use this as a base to calculate all future path names.

For example,

```
$base = dirname( __FILE__ ); # Path to directory containing this file
include( "{$base}/includes/Common.php" ); # Kick off some magic
```

Comment: You got my +1, but please avoid "{$var}". Why not `$base . '/includes/Common.php'`?

Comment: I prefer setting the include-path and not using variables in each include/require statement.

Comment: eyelidnessless: I find it a touch easier to read. There's no difference between the two.

Answer (score 1):

it's probably easier to just use an absolute path to reference:

```
set_include_path('/path/to/files');
```

this way you have a reference point for all your future includes. includes are handled relative to the point they were called, which can cause a bit of confusion in certain scenarios.

as an example, given a sample folder structure (`/home/files`):

```
index.php
test/
  test.php
test2/
  test2.php

// /home/files/index.php
include('test/test.php');

// /home/files/test/test.php
include('../test2/test2.php');
```

if you call index.php, it will try to include the following files:

```
/home/files/test/test.php // expected
/home/test2/test2.php // maybe not expected
```

which may not be what you expect. calling test.php will call `/home/files/test2/test.php` as expected.

the conclusion being, the includes will be relative to the original calling point. to clarify, this affects `set_include_path()` if it is relative as well. consider the following (using the same directory structure):

```
<?php
// location: /home/files/index.php
   set_include_path('../'); // our include path is now /home/

   include('files/test/test.php'); // try to include /home/files/test/test.php
   include('test2/test2.php'); // try to include /home/test2/test2.php
   include('../test3.php'); // try to include /test3.php
?>
```

Comment: where exactly does that start? is it relative to apache or is it set in php.ini or is it the php directory itself?

Comment: by default the include is relative to the calling location (ie the directory your script which calls include is in)

Comment: in regards to set_include_path('../'); - if i wanted to set the include path to 2 directories up how would i put it?

Comment: sorry never mind, figured out that each . represents one step up